# Elasticsearch send a get request not post

Tags: javascript, jquery, elasticsearch

This is my code for sending a `GET` request to my elasticseach server:

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});
client.search({
  index: 'deals',
  type: 'couchbaseDocument',
  body: {
    query: {
      match: {
        source: 'doc.amenities'
      }
    }
  }
}).then(function (resp) {
    var hits = resp.hits.hits;
}, function (err) {
    console.trace(err.message);
});
```

However, this is the actual request that is being send, `after checking chrome developing tools` :

```
 POST "http://localhost:9200/deals/couchbaseDocument/_search".
```

but I need it to be `GET` not `POST`

how please?

I already checked the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html):

and they just say how to send `head` and `post`, there is no `GET` requests

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers do not allow you to append a body to a `GET` request, which is the reason that the library does not work this way, as well as why the REST API accepts `POST` for what is purely a read only request.

You could override the behavior by [changing the default `method` used](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/master/src/lib/apis/1_6.js#L5519) (by [passing your own `method`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-conventions.html#_generic_parameters)), but I would suggest against doing that in order to guarantee compatibility. I assume that you are fighting a proxy to ensure that only read only requests are allowed. Instead of trying to fight the browser(s) to work for the proxy, you should just make exceptions for `POST` requests whose URLs end with `/_search` to Elasticsearch.